# Why does net positive suction head (NSPH) include velocity head?

Tags: pumps

When the absolute pressure dips below the vapour pressure, cavitation occurs. Why would dynamic pressure be taken into account in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Because dynamic pressure is contributing to the total pressure and, when checking for the possibility of cavitation all terms must be included or at least accounted for.

Comment: So the total pressure, not the static pressure determines whether cavitation occurs?

Comment: One must account for the static head pressure along with any momentum associated pressure

Answer (score 1):

According to [Pump & Systems](https://www.pumpsandsystems.com/topics/understanding-npsh-npsh-definitions),

> Note that suction pressure is stagnation pressure (total pressure); it includes velocity head. Adding velocity head puts all pumps on the same basis, otherwise a pump would require different amounts of NPSH when tested with different sizes of suction lines (assuming that suction pressure is measured in the suction line, which is normally the case).